# Piping StdOut adds more text

Tags: command-line, bash, unix, pipe, stdout

I am running a simple command (some Kafka related stuff):

```
curl localhost:8083
```

Its output is very simple:

```
root@debian:/etc/kafka# curl localhost:8083/
{"version":"0.11.0.0-cp1","commit":"6a8cf706ddc9ab6a"}root@debian:/etc/kafka#
```

But now, when I use utility tool `jq` to format json, more lines get added:

```
root@debian:/etc/kafka# curl localhost:8083/ | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    54  100    54    0     0   1492      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1500
{
  "version": "0.11.0.0-cp1",
  "commit": "6a8cf706ddc9ab6a"
}
```

Same happens if I pipe it to `less` or `cat` in the expected way `curl ... | less`. So this has nothing to do with `jq` itself.

My knowledge of all the stdin, stdout, stderr, pipes (that are just joins of stdout to sdtin), file redirects `> < 2>`, etc.. doesn't explain this behaviour. :(

Comment: `curl -q localhost:8083`

Comment: @EugenRieck it doesn't help (but even if it would, it wouldn't explain the issue)

Comment: `curl` checks, if stdout is a TTY or a pipe and adapts its output according to it. So to shut it up you need `curl -s localhost:8083/` (-s for silent, not -q for quiet as I thought)

Comment: Thanks, I am happy to accept it as an answer :) @EugenRieck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many UNIX tools, the output of `curl` depends upon what type of device stdout is attached to. In this case, piping the ourput through `jq` changes the type from `TTY` to `pipe`, resulting in unwanted additional output.

`curl` has a command-line switch `-s`, that silences this additional output, so running `curl -s localhost:8083/ | jq` shold solve the issue.